# Why does this generic java method accept two objects of different type?

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters

This method shall take two objects **of the same type** and return one of those objects by random:

```
public static <T> T random(T o1, T o2)
{
   return Math.random() < 0.5 ? o1 : o2;
}
```

Now, why does the compiler accept two parameters with distinctive types?

```
random("string1", new Integer(10)); // Compiles without errors
```

**EDIT:**
Now that I know that both parameters are getting implicitly upcasted, I wonder why the compiler **does** complain when calling the following method:

```
public static <T> List<T> randomList(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) {
        return Math.random() < 0.5 ? l1 : l2;
    }
```

Call:

```
randomList(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<Integer>()); // Does not Compile
```

If those ArrayList Parameters are also getting upcasted to Object, why does it give me an error this time?

Comment: Because they're both `Object`s.

Comment: @user1914126.. As it stands, your code should not compile. You are missing a `new` before `Integer(10)`.

Comment: Yep, if you want the compiler to complain you would have to tell it what T is supposed to be when you call the method, e.g. `MyClass.<String>random("string1", new Integer(10));`. That would be an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`T` is inferred to be `Object`, and both arguments are getting implicitly upcast.**

Thus the code is equivalent to:

```
Main.<Object>random((Object)"string1", (Object)new Integer(10));
```

What may be even more surprising is that the following compiles:

```
random("string1", 10);
```

The second argument is getting auto-boxed into an `Integer`, and then both arguments are getting upcast to `Object`.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the are also both `Serializable` and `Comparable`. Hang on, `Comparable<?>`, er, `Comparable<? extends Comparable<?> & Serializable>`, oh `<Comparable<? extends Comparable<` oh I give up. Assign it to something silly and look the the compiler error message.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: You are quite right, although I haven't quite figured out how to work those details into the answer without obscuring the point.

Answer (score 5):

`T` is inferred to be the a common super type of `String` and `Integer`, which is

```
Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends ... ...
```

well, nobody needs to care about that.

You can add a little more constraints on the parameter types

```
public static <T1,T2 extends T1> T1 random(T1 o1, T2 o2)
```

In your list example, you need wildcards to get the similar effect

```
public static <T> List<? extends T> randomList(
                                    List<? extends T> l1, List<? extends T> l2)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Know that I know that both parameters are getting implicitly upcasted,
>   I wonder why the compiler does complain when calling the following
>   method:

Because even when `A` is a subtype of `B`, `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>` if A and B are different.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't call it in a safe, genericized way. Try

```
MyClass.<String>random("string1", new Integer(10));
```

And you'll get a compilation error.

Or let the compiler infer the type, and you should also get a compilation error:

```
String s = random("string1", new Integer(10));
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the type of a method to get generic behavior. `Integer x = random(1, 2)` is valid as well.

Comment: Yes, I was still editing my answer to add a note about type inference.

Comment: @JanDvorak or if there is `void foo(String s1, String s2)` then `foo(random(....))`. The point is that there isn't enough in the call by itself to tie `T` to `String`.